# Custom Spinner with an EditText field and an Image button

Tags: android, spinner, android-custom-view

I'm trying to create a custom spinner which uses an EditText field, and an ImageButton. I however cannot find how to get the same pop up menu I originally had in my Spinner to show after pressing the ImageButton.

[`This`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619576/android-drawing-a-button-as-a-spinner) was the closest question I could find but it isn't really the same as my problem at all.

Here is my old spinner code:

```
apModeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, res.getStringArray( R.array.anti_pump_ap_mode_array )  );
apModeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
apModeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.apModeSpinner);
apModeSpinner.setAdapter(apModeAdapter);
apModeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
```

Or, using an `ArrayList` instead of an array in my `Resources:`

```
pumpCountAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pumpCountList);
pumpCountAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
pumpCountSpinner.setAdapter(pumpCountAdapter);
pumpCountSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
```

I do not want a [`PopUp Menu`](http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/03/example-of-using-popupmenu.html).

I do want something similar to a [`ContextMenu`](http://saga-androidapplication.blogspot.in/2011/05/dialog-list-item.html), but I don't want the buttons it has at the bottom. I tried implementing it myself and removing them, but it doesn't work cleanly. The `onClick` method only has a parameter for which button was pressed.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(MoreParameters.this);
    ab.setTitle(R.string.anti_pump_ap_mode);
    ab.setSingleChoiceItems(res.getStringArray( R.array.anti_pump_ap_mode_array ), 0,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // onClick Action             
    }
});
ab.show();
```

Although the `ContextMenu` is close to what I want, I would really like to replicate the spinners shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to change `ab.setSingleChoiceItems()` to `ab.setItems()` which requires the removal of the `0` parameter it was passed.

This:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(MoreParameters.this);
    ab.setTitle(R.string.anti_pump_ap_mode);
    ab.setSingleChoiceItems(res.getStringArray( R.array.anti_pump_ap_mode_array ), 0,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // onClick Action             
    }
});
ab.show();
```

Becomes this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(MoreParameters.this);
    ab.setTitle(R.string.anti_pump_ap_mode);
    ab.setItems(res.getStringArray( R.array.anti_pump_ap_mode_array ),new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // onClick Action             
    }
});
ab.show();
```