# How to edit Widget.Spinner press effect for color change in Android

Tags: android, styles, spinner

I am using 
following style to show spinner which is having custom style

```
         <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tblRwSpn11"
                style="@style/TableRowStyle" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/btnDashCust1"
                    style="@style/ButtonStyleSpinner1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </TableRow>

 <style name="ButtonStyleSpinner1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">35dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/twelveTextSize</item>        
    </style>
in my SDK style.xml


 <style name="Widget.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_dropdown</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerMode">dialog</item>

        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:drawable/spinner_dropdown_background</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-10dip</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:popupPromptView">@android:layout/simple_dropdown_hint</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

and  `@android:drawable/btn_dropdown` as follows

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_normal" />
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_disabled" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_normal" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_disabled_focused" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_disabled" />
</selector>
```

output :

[image]

My Theme

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/thin_ab_style</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">2dp</item>
</style>

<style name="thin_ab_style" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:height">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

it shows orange color for my spinner even if i have not set 
so from where it is getting set? Please check above styles I applied to spinner 
the press effect should show either blue or gray according to theme

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014152/android-changing-colors-with-themes hope you find some

Comment: @DigveshPatel thank for help but tht orange color is due parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner" which shows on press orange color so how to change color of pressed spinner inside SDK style.xml

Comment: Try to make your custom adapter for spinner item.

Comment: @DigveshPatel if i remove parent property is shows me spinner like -select customer- without press effect

Comment: hmmm  it means "select custome" is one of your spinner data. so its work like this . no issue in your code . just try to set hint not data to spinner

Comment: @DigveshPatel see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619576/android-drawing-a-button-as-a-spinner

Answer (score 0):

Just write a basic `Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Type>` like doing as List View.

Override getView method for that view that you want to change.

Override getDropDown view that opened when spinner pressed.

Lastly dont forget to call `Spinner.setAdapter(mAdapter)`

And you can use your custom layouts to change colors or anything you want.

Good luck there.

Comment: thank you for help i am already using custom spinner with custom style plz read code posted

Comment: What i am saying you dont need to custom style. You can do it by custom layouts which has selector at backgrounds.

Also dont forget to add clickable=true at the root layout of your cell.