# Make android button look like a spinner

Tags: android, uibutton

I have a buttons and I want to make them look like a spinner.
I've found this post from 2011:
[Android: Drawing a button as a spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619576/android-drawing-a-button-as-a-spinner)

And none of the solutions worked for me.

It's better if I could use my customed background.
Those are the buttons:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_msn_act_type"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:onClick="showPopup"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:text="Order Type"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

<Button
                android:id="@+id/new_msn_datetimepick"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_border"
                android:onClick="pickDateTime"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="Date and Time"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

I tried each one of the solutions suggested in the post, including

```
                style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
And they didn't work. How can I solve it ? Thanks
```

I need it to be a Button, because I want to use drawable style as background, and I want it to open PopupMenu and I worked hard for the popup to present icons correctly...

Comment: It would be far easier making a spinner look like a button

Comment: The easiest thing may be to use a spinner and override its onClick.  A lot of buttons you see aren't buttons, but are other views like TextViews or FrameLayouts with an onClick set.

Comment: @GabeSechan it sounded tempting, I created Spinner, and added: android:onClick="showPopup" (Like the original button's) 
But it didn't work: 
                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead

Comment: Also adding Icon to my button will also help. How can I do it  ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with:

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_down_float"
```

You can also choose custom drawables